# TypeError: Cannot read property in but property is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird issue `TypeError: Cannot read property 'allowed' of undefined` on last element in `$scope.leaveType`.

**Update :**

Thanks @dusky its fixed the problem, but now am getting below errors in console, **but app is working** here is screenshot

Full code of controller is [here](http://pastebin.com/L70pkbJp)

its seems its not getting `$scope.myLeaves[id]`

```
$scope.myLeaves = { "1": 18, "2": 12, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 1, "6": 1, "7": 1};
```

[image]

Please help what i have missed here.

```
  $scope.leaveType = [
    { "id": "1", "name": "Paid Leave", "allowed": 18},
    { "id": "2", "name": "Caual Leave", "allowed": 12},
    { "id": "3", "name": "Maternity Leave", "allowed": 0},
    { "id": "4", "name": "Paternity Leave", "allowed": 0},
    { "id": "5", "name": "Celebration Leave", "allowed": 1},
    { "id": "6", "name": "Compensatory Off","allowed": 1},
    { "id": "7", "name": "Optional Holiday Leave", "allowed": 1}
  ];

  $scope.myLeaves = { "1": 18, "2": 12, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 1, "6": 1, "7": 1};

  $scope.taken  = function (index) {
        var allowed = $scope.leaveType[index].allowed,
            leaveTypeId = $scope.leaveType[index].id,
            taken = (parseFloat(allowed,10)) - (parseFloat($scope.myLeaves[leaveTypeId], 10));

        return taken;
  }
    //Get remaining leaves in a category
  $scope.remaining  = function (index) {
        var allowed = $scope.leaveType[index].allowed,
            leaveTypeId = $scope.leaveType[index].id,
            remain = (parseFloat(allowed,10)) - $scope.taken(leaveTypeId, allowed);

        return remain;
  }
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i6gFvDu2fmBdDniWVYig?p=preview)

Comment: `remain = … - $scope.taken(leaveTypeId, allowed);`, but `leaveTypeId = $scope.leaveType[index].id;`: no, `$scope.leaveType[7]` doesn't exist.

Comment: I am getting the `myLeaves `from `$scope.myLeaves = angular.fromJson($scope.leaveSummary.allocation);` from db stored as string, can it be the reason for `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' to '7' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remaining function is wrong. `$scope.taken` takes the index as argument. By the way: [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) doesn't take 2 arguments (parseInt does). And it's not needed here as allowed is already a number.

The error is on this line:

```
remain = (parseFloat(allowed,10)) - $scope.taken(leaveTypeId, allowed);
```

It should be:

```
remain = allowed - $scope.taken(index);
```

So it becomes:

```
  $scope.remaining  = function (index) {
        var allowed = $scope.leaveType[index].allowed,
            remain = allowed - $scope.taken(index);

        return remain;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it works now, But in console am getting `Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
                    {{ remaining($index) }}
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' to '7' of undefined`

Comment: @Saqueib I would suggest to work with the leaveType Ids instead of row indexes. I made you an [example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RerVBdd9bfh4Amky4udr). It works for me.

Comment: @dusky I have tried you option but i not sure why the hell its giving `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' to '7' of undefined` but i can see its on page its working

Comment: I have shared all code on controller, [please check](http://pastebin.com/L70pkbJp)